# HTML : Does the beforeunload event always get triggered

Tags: javascript, html

To update a website I need to track periodically a status field in my database. To achieve this I setup a timer like this;

```
var id = window.setInterval("getState()", 1000);
```

`getState()` calls via `AJAX` every second the database and returns the value of specific status field. The timer is running while the browser window is open. When the user closes its browser window I need to clear the timer which I do with this code :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  setState(0);
  clearInterval(id);
});
```

Now my question is : Does this `event` get triggered always ? Is this a reliable way in modern browser or are there exceptions ?

EDIT :

I add `setState()` on the event `beforeunload` to update the DB when the window is closing. I forgot this before, sorry ...

Comment: It's very reliable and I've not heard of any exceptions. Why are you passing the interval handler as a string? You could just use `setInterval(getState,1000)`. Actually, a quick read up shows that it's not recommended to use the string approach as it is essentially and `eval`.

Comment: The timer should automatically be cleared when the window is closed, so I don't think you'd need the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: Thats a good point, but I forgot to tell that I need to update the state in the DB as well, when the windo is closing. See my edit above.

Comment: @ somethinghere - To pass the method as a string I got from a blog page. Surprisingly it worked and without not. So what is the difference ? I guess the paranthesis were guilty, So when I pass the method like you recommend `setInterval(getState, 1000)` it works too. Strange anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `beforeunload` event will always get triggered if the user closes the browser window.
2. The `beforeunload` event will always get triggered if the device restarts properly.
3. The `beforeunload` event will **not** get triggered if power is cut from the device (battery pull, unplugging)

A side note: if the browser window is closed, the timer with your AJAX call will be stopped automatically.

Comment: Refering your side note: setState() will be called `beforeunload`. In turn setState() will initiate an AJAX request. Will that be processed before closing the window ?  (I am not expecting a callback on that request)

Comment: `setState` will be triggered, and the request will be sent to the server. So any actions taken on your server end will be performed. There will be nothing on your client end to handle a response from your server, however, so your UI will not be updated. Your UI will be closed by that time anyway.